# ¿Cómo formatear un numero con ceros a la izquierda en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hola necesito convertir un número entero a string y a su ves definirle una longitud determinada de caracteres al numero, en caso de que la longitud sea menor que se rellene con ceros a la izquierda, un ejemplo

```
324  ->   00324  // suponiendo que haya definido en 5 la longitud
```

En python habia una funcion especifica que hacia esto llamada [zfill](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/zfill.html)

```
>>> '234'.zfill(5)
00234
```

Existe algun equivalente en javascript o como seria una funcion que haga lo mismo.

Saludos

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pensando en la lógica de la función de Python hice esta función, que recibe como parámetros tu número y el ancho deseado (la longitud, como definiste en tu pregunta).

Si el ancho es menor o igual al largo del string del número, se regresa el número.

De lo contrario, se ponen X ceros antes del número, donde X es la resta entre el ancho dado como parámetro y el largo del string del número.

Adicionalmente, y replicando lo que pasa en la función de Python, esta función contempla el caso de usar la función sobre un número negativo. Para ello, se trabaja con valores absolutos, de modo que, si tu número es negativo, se agrega el signo `-` al inicio del string, los ceros que se van a agregar o no, y el valor absoluto del número al final.

```js
function zfill(number, width) {
    var numberOutput = Math.abs(number); /* Valor absoluto del número */
    var length = number.toString().length; /* Largo del número */ 
    var zero = "0"; /* String de cero */  
    
    if (width <= length) {
        if (number < 0) {
             return ("-" + numberOutput.toString()); 
        } else {
             return numberOutput.toString(); 
        }
    } else {
        if (number < 0) {
            return ("-" + (zero.repeat(width - length)) + numberOutput.toString()); 
        } else {
            return ((zero.repeat(width - length)) + numberOutput.toString()); 
        }
    }
}

console.log(zfill(324, 2)); // 324
console.log(zfill(324, 3)); // 324
console.log(zfill(324, 4)); // 0324
console.log(zfill(324, 5)); // 00324
console.log(zfill(324, 10)); // 0000000324
console.log(zfill(-324, 5)); // -0324
```

Comment: ciertamente es la mejor solución se me había pasado la posibilidad de que fuese un numero negativo. Muchas gracias

Comment: Para que funcione con cadenas cambiar "var length = number.toString().length;" por " var length = numberOutput.toString().length;"

Answer (score 4):

Pues puedes usar esto:

```js
function PadLeft(value, length) {
    return (value.toString().length < length) ? PadLeft("0" + value, length) : 
    value;
}
console.log(PadLeft(5,4))
```

Comment: Podrías explicar mejor tu código y añadir unos ejemplos

Answer (score 4):

Simple función encontrado de esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-pad-a-value-with-leading-zeros) en **SOen**:

```js
function zeroFill( number, width )
{
  width -= number.toString().length;
  if ( width > 0 )
  {
    return new Array( width + (/\./.test( number ) ? 2 : 1) ).join( '0' ) + number;
  }
  return number + ""; // siempre devuelve tipo cadena
}

console.log( zeroFill(324, 5) );
```

**Actualización:**

A partir de *[ES2017](https://flaviocopes.com/es2017/) podemos usar el método [string.padStart()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/padStart)

> **PARÁMETROS**
>
> `str.padStart(longitudTotal [, valorRelleno])`
>
> **longitudTotal**: Define la longitud total del objeto. Si este parámetro es más pequeño que la longitud del objeto actual se devuelve el objeto sin ser modificado.
>
> **valorRelleno** (*opcional*): El valor por defecto es '' (un espacio). Rellena hacía a la izquierda con el valor del relleno. Si el valor del relleno es más largo que la longitud total será recortada el valor de relleno.
>
> **VALOR DEVUELTO**
>
> Una cadena (string) con la longitud especificada y el relleno aplicada

```js
console.log( '234'.padStart(6) );
console.log( '234'.padStart(6, 0) );
console.log( '234'.padStart(0) );
console.log( '234'.padStart(2, 0) );
console.log( '234'.padStart(6, 'abcdefgh') );
```

Y con [string.padEnd()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd) conseguimos lo mismo pero hacía a la derecha del objetivo.

*[Ver compatibilidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/padStart#Compatibilidad_con_navegadores)

Answer (score 2):

funcion de una linea.
recibe 2 parametros
  number: el número a completar con zeros a la izquierda
  len: el tamaño de él string deseado

la función toma el string "0" y lo repite, para repetir toma la variable len y le resta el largo del número que queremos completar, y así crea los zeros que hacen falta y concatena al número pasado por parametro.

```js
const fill = (number, len) =>
  "0".repeat(len - number.toString().length) + number.toString();


console.log(fill(123, 5));
// print  "00123"

console.log(fill(1234, 8));
// print  "00000123"
```

Comment: Hola!, podrías añadir una explicación a tu código?

Comment: @Riaven listo !

Comment: una variacion de tu respuesta `new Array(len - number.toString().length).fill("0").join("") + number.toString();`

Answer (score 1):

Para hacerla semejante al uso en Python podrías hacer esta función:

```
Number.prototype.zfill = function(size) {
  var numb = String(this);
  while (numb.length < (size || 2)) {
    numb = '0' + numb;
  }
  return numb;
}

(234).zfill(5); // '00234'
```

Answer (score 1):

para convertir un número a String sería:

```
var num=123;
var numstring=num.toString();
```

Para añadir ceros a la izquierda sería:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ponerCeros(num) {
  while (num.value.length<5)
    num.value = '0'+num.value;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" onblur="ponerCeros(this)" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Esta solución tiene un problema ya que antes de evaluar se deberian quitar los 0 excedentes por lo que solo funciona para la primera ves, si luego agregas un número a la derecha no actualizara el tamaño.

Answer (score 0):

Dejo algo más sencillo por si alguien está con el mismo problema.
Para convertir el entero a string podés usar la función "toString()", y para agregar los ceros a la izquierda "padStart" o "padEnd" en caso de que los necesites a la derecha.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var num = 117;
  var n = num.toString().padStart(6,'0');
  var m = num.toString().padEnd(6,'0');
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n +'\r\n'+ m;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Valor entero: 117</p>
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Convertir</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log('234'.padStart(6, 0)); //000234
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución pero agrega una explicación, esta publicación fue reportada como de "baja calidad" te sugerimos revisa [answer] y editar tu publicación, saludos.